# in React How to Update the State of an element in a mapped array of elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have two data objects and 3 hierarchical components below, or in sandbox [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-imypsy?file=index.js). The data contain a list of questions, each rendered with input box right below it that allow multiple replies. However, I don't know how to proper update the state of the correct question after typing in a reply to a particular question.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import QA from './qa';
//parent of qa.js

const questions = [
  {id : 1,
  question: "where is the origin of chihuahua?"},
  {id : 2,
  question: "when does the great migration happen in Africa?"}
]

const answers = [
  {
    id : 1,
    id_question : 1,
    answer: "Mexico"
    },
  {
    id : 2,
    id_question : 1,
   answer: "Argentina"
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    id_question : 2,
    answer: "Apr"
    },
  {
    id : 4,
    id_question : 2,
    answer: "May"}
]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    q : questions, 
    a : answers
    }

  handleSubmit = (val, index) => {
    alert('index',index)
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      a: [...this.state.a, {id_question: index, answer: val}]
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      questions.map((q, index) =>
        <QA 
          key={index} 
          question={q.question}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
      )  
    )
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

qa.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Answer from './answer';
import  "./style.css"
//parent of answer.js

export default class QA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { question } = this.props
    const { text } = this.state
    return (
      <div class='qa-block'>
        <div>Question: {question}</div>
        <Answer onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and answer.js

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
};

export default class Answer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { text } = this.state
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Answers</h4>
        <input type="text"
          value={text} 
          onInput={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} />
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.text)}>Send to the parent</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

A few newbie questions:

1. where do I call index such that setState append to state.answer that right question id and increment answer id by 1?
2. should I have nested answers as a property of question instead?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass questionNo as props to qa & ans components, then retrive through the callback like following:

in index.js

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      questions.map((q, index) =>
        <QA 
          questionNo={index} 
          question={q.question}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
      )  
    )
  }
```

in qa.js

```
render() {
    const { question, questionNo } = this.props
    const { text } = this.state
    return (
      <div class='qa-block'>
        <div>Question: {question}</div>
        <Answer questionNo={questionNo} onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

in answer.js

```
render() {
    const { text } = this.state
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Answers</h4>
        <input type="text"
          value={text} 
          onInput={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} />
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.text, this.props.questionNo)}>Send to the parent</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

after this you will get index of clicked item in index.js

Answer (score 1):

So to identify the question you need to pass the id_question to the submit button, so if you have the parameter then on the callback you will be able to get it.

once you get you can do a find on the answers array of objects and update the userTyped answer.

```
  handleSubmit = (val, text) => {
    const typedAnswer = {...this.state.a.find(ans => ans.id_question === val), userTypedAnswer: text};
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      a: [...this.state.a, typedAnswer]
    });
  }
```

code

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import QA from './qa';
//parent of qa.js

const questions = [
  {id: 1,
  question: "where is the origin of chihuahua?"},
  {id: 2,
  question: "when does the great migration happen in africa?"}
]

const answers = [
  {id_question: 1,
  answer: "Mexico"},
  {id_question: 1,
  answer: "Argentina"},
  {id_question: 2,
  answer: "Apr"},
  {id_question: 2,
  answer: "May"}
]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    q : questions, 
    a : answers
    }

  handleSubmit = (val, text) => {
    const typedAnswer = {...this.state.a.find(ans => ans.id_question === val), userTypedAnswer: text};
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      a: [...this.state.a, typedAnswer]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>{
         questions.map((q, index) =>
        <QA 
          key={index} 
          question={q}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
      )  

      }
       <p>User Typed Answers and questions after submit</p>
       {
         this.state.a.map(ans => (
           ans.userTypedAnswer && <div>
            <span>{ans.id_question}</span>: <span>{ans.userTypedAnswer}</span>
           </div>
         ))
       }
      </>
    )
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

// answer.js

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
};

export default class Answer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { text } = this.state
    const {onSubmit, qid} = this.props
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Answers</h4>
        <input type="text"
          value={text} 
          onInput={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} />
        <button onClick={() => onSubmit(qid, this.state.text)}>Send to the parent</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

qa.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Answer from './answer';
import  "./style.css"
//parent of answer.js

export default class QA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { question: {question, id}, onSubmit } = this.props
    const { text } = this.state
    return (
      <div class='qa-block'>
        <div>Question: {question}</div>
        <Answer onSubmit={onSubmit} qid={id}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wkncb5?file=qa.js)